# Generate a QQPlot for all numeric variables in a dataframe using r

Tags: r, dataframe, normal-distribution

I would like to generate separate qqplots for all numeric variables in a dataframe to assess univariate normality (only an x variable is required). The plots do not have to be stored as a list -- only displayed in r-studio.

I've tried multiple approaches with no luck including qqline/qqnorm (base r), various iteration of qplot (ggplot2), and qqPlot (EnvStats) in conjunction with apply and a for loop.  Below are a few examples.  txhousing is from ggplot2.

Use any library you deem appropriate to address the intent of the question.

```
df <- txhousing

df.num.vec <- names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)]

df.num <- df[, df.num.vec]

apply(df.num,2,qqPlot)
```

This results in a series of errors:

```
Warning messages:
1: In is.not.finite.warning(x) :
  There were 568 nonfinite values in x : 568 NA's
2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
  568 observations with NA/NaN/Inf in 'x' removed.
3: In is.not.finite.warning(x) :
  There were 568 nonfinite values in x : 568 NA's
4: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
  568 observations with NA/NaN/Inf in 'x' removed.
5: In is.not.finite.warning(x) :
  There were 616 nonfinite values in x : 616 NA's
6: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
  616 observations with NA/NaN/Inf in 'x' removed.
7: In is.not.finite.warning(x) :
  There were 1424 nonfinite values in x : 1424 NA's
8: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
  1424 observations with NA/NaN/Inf in 'x' removed.
9: In is.not.finite.warning(x) :
  There were 1467 nonfinite values in x : 1467 NA's
10: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
  1467 observations with NA/NaN/Inf in 'x' removed.
```

```
df <- txhousing

for (i in seq_along(df)) {
  x <- df[[i]]
  if (!is.numeric(x)) next
  qqPlot(df[,i])
}
```

This results in:

```
Error in qqPlot(df[, i]) : 'x' must be a numeric vector
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? `qqPlot` is not a base R function. What packages are you using? Did you mean `qqplot`? (R is case sensitive). Where do you want the plots to "go" exactly?

Comment: You can store it in a list i.e. `lst1 <- list()` and inside the loop, `lst1 <- c(lst1, list(qqPlot(df[,i])))`

Comment: If you are using `qqplot`, you may need the `x` and `y` variables i.e. `qqplot(df$year, df$sales)`

Comment: If you want to plot on a single page with `qqPlot`, you may need to adjust the `par` i.e. `par(mfrow = c(3, 3))` and then do `apply(df.num,2,qqPlot)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already filtered numeric columns saved in df.num, you can directly use df.num in the for() loop:

```
#Using ggplot to create qqplots and save in the list
library(ggplot2)
# Create a list
qq_list <- list()

# the for loop
for (var in names(df.num)) {
  # Create a Q-Q plot and store it in the list
  qq_list[[var]] <- ggplot(df.num, aes(get(var))) +
    geom_qq() +
    ggtitle(paste0("Q-Q Plot of ", var))
}

# Print the list of plots
print(qq_list)
```

Using car

```
library(car)
for (i in 1:ncol(df.num)) {
  
  qqPlot(df.num[, i], main = names(df.num)[i])
}
```

If you want to save your plots into for example a .pdf file you can do as below:

```
myqq = "qq.pdf"

pdf(file=myqq) 

for (i in 1:ncol(df.num)) {
  
  qqPlot(df.num[, i], main = names(df.num)[i])
}

dev.off()
```

You can access the pdf file in your working directory with the name of 'qq.pdf'

Comment: Turns the following error: Error in if (!all(as.character(extreme) == nms)) names(extreme) <- nms : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Why are you not using your data directly? It is hard to figure out as the structure of your data is not known. Also I think the qqPlot() from car package doesn't work with the list. If it doesn't not matter, you may use the base R qqplot function

Comment: as stated in the post the data source is txhousing -- it's available in ggplot2.  Alternately mtcars could be used.